# RoutingRules on AWS S3 Static website hosting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have successfully configured my S3 bucket to serve a static website and also redirect to a lambda function if a file is not found in the bucket.

```
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <KeyPrefixEquals/>
      <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>404</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <Protocol>https</Protocol>
      <HostName>mylambda.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com</HostName>
      <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>/?key=</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
      <HttpRedirectCode>307</HttpRedirectCode>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

it works fine if I use the http url of the static website

http://mybucket.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/some-file.gif

but it doesn´t work if I use the https bucket url. it returns **AccessDenied**

https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/some-file.gif

I also tryied adding cloudfront and the issue is the same.
https://mycloudfront.cloudfront.net/some-file.gif gives me the same **AccessDenied**

is like not working for https maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first url:

> mybucket.**s3-website**-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/some-file.gif

is a [website endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteEndpoints.html). It only supports HTTP, **not** HTTPS. [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/s3.html) write:

> The website endpoints do not support HTTPS or Amazon S3 Access Points.

The second url:

> **s3.amazonaws.com**/mybucket/some-file.gif

is [Legacy Global Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html) still used N. Virginia region. These (i.e. service endpoints) are used [to](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/s3.html):

> connect programmatically to an AWS service

They [support](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/s3.html) both HTTP and HTTPS.

Therefore, answering to your question, the **https:**//mybucket.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/some-file.gif fails because HTTPS is not supported for website endpoints.

The https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/some-file.gif fails because this is used for programmatic access, not by using browser or curl. But if you set your objects as **public**, you should be able to access them nevertheless.

For CloudFront you would need to provide more information, or create new question. It depends how you setup your CF disto and bucket.

Comment: ok so there's no way to do it with s3 endpoints. I think cloudfront could work but it could cause an infinite loop because the error page will be cached.

Comment: for the website endpoints, cloudfront is typically used to provide https. There are no loops. I would suggest to create a new question specific to cloudfront and who you are setting it up and what's the issue.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion @Marcin here´s the follow up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61024036/disable-cloudfront-cache-if-file-is-not-found

Comment: @handsome No problem and thanks for the link. If you are happy with the answer, accepting it would be appreciated.