# Disable Cloudfront cache if file is not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I created a Cloudfront distribution in front of an S3 bucket with a RoutingRule to redirect to a lambda function if the requested file is not found. I´m using this to resize images.

**Desired flow:**

1. Request the file to Cloudfront
2. File not found in Cloudfront check S3
3. File not found in S3 redirect to the lambda function
4. Lambda will find the original file, resize it and redirect back to the Cloudfront url.

**Redirect rule set on s3 website:**

```
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <KeyPrefixEquals/>
      <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>404</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <Protocol>https</Protocol>
      <HostName>mylambda.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com</HostName>
      <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>/?key=</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
      <HttpRedirectCode>307</HttpRedirectCode>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

I´m having a problem with the step 4 when the lambda function redirects back to the original url
Cloudfront cached the 404? and the routing rule from S3 is redirecting again to the lambda function causing a loop.

1. I confirmed that the lambda function generated the file.
2. if I invalidate the file on Cloudfront I successfully see it served from S3)

I tried adding a 0 TTL to the 404 error page but didn´t help.

[image: Custom Error Response]

the redirect rule returns a 307 status code `[Temporary Redirect]`. But I don´t know how to set a 0 TTL on this. I couldn´t find the option on the Cloudfront custom error response page.

[image]

According to [this article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/http-3xx-status-codes.html). the 307 is cached. need to set a rule for it... somewhere .

This is a follow up question on [RoutingRules on AWS S3 Static website hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61005669/routingrules-on-aws-s3-static-website-hosting/61007940?noredirect=1#comment107956292_61007940)

I appreciate your help.

**Update:**
1. Removed the RoutingRule on S3
2. Added a new origin to the Cloudfront distribution (API gateway)

[image]

the lambda function now returns

```
    return {
        statusCode: "200",
        body: "image converted",
    };
```

Checking Cloudwatch logs I don´t see the lambda function getting invoked and when I go to https://myCloudfront.cloudfront.net/photos/resized/test.jpg

I only see a plain 404

[image]

I also added a custom error page with a 0 TTL for 404

the good news is if I go to the api gateway passing key=/photos/resized/test.jpg
and then go to https://my.cloudfront.net/photos/resized/test.jpg it works. it reads the image correctly.

I think the problem is with the failover that´s not triggering the api gateway call.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could, of course, use a Lambda@Edge Origin Response trigger, to modify the response and set the header you want.  This would, in a sense, be the "most correct" and therefore "most desirable" solution, but only in a theoretical sense, because it introduces unnecessary cost and complexity.

Default TTL is the value that is used by CloudFront, internally, when no `Cache-Control` response header is found... so, you could set that to 0 and include correct `Cache-Control` headers when creating your S3 objects, so that the Default TTL wouldn't be used except for the redirects.  What I don't like about this is that there's no header to insist that the browser also not cache the redirect.

But you don't actually need to return a redirect to the browser, here.  You don't need a redirect at all.

> With CloudFront’s Origin Failover capability, you can setup two origins for your distributions - primary and secondary, such that your content is served from your secondary origin if CloudFront detects that your primary origin is unavailable.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/amazon-cloudfront-announces-support-for-origin-failover/

The word "unavailable" is unnecessarily vague, here, because this feature does more that that, and it will do what you want.  To set what triggers origin "failover"...

> You can choose any combination of the following status codes: 500, 502, 503, 504, 404, or 403.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/high_availability_origin_failover.html#concept_origin_groups.creating

So just the normal bucket behavior is sufficient, no redirect rules required.

Note that with this setup, the final response is the only thing that can be cached by CloudFront -- whether that reaponse is from the primary (S3) or secondary (Lambda via API Gateway) origin -- so this elmiminates the issue with transient responses being cached.

Note also that despite the use of the word "failover," CloudFront does not maintain a conceptual model of the state of the origin, so each request stands on its own and will go to the primary origin even when other requests are "failing."

Comment: thank you michael. this looks promising. but is assuming two origins and technically the requested file doesn´t exist yet (lambda generates it and then saves it into s3) how to specifiy the failover is the same origin but after lambda generates the file? also you said I dont need redirection. you mean no bucket redirection but the lambda redirection is still needed right?

Comment: The failover is API Gateway and the Lambda function, which receives requests that the bucket answers with 403/404, does the work, then redirects the browsr back, with appropriate `Cache-Control` headers OR just returns the generated object payload after storing it in the bucket -- assuming it's smaller than the Lambda payload limit.  The point here is that no redirect to the Lambda function is required since CloudFront will automatically try to fetch the original path from the alternate origin.

Comment: oh I see. and how to tell the lambda function which file to process? the lambda right now is using: const key = event.queryStringParameters.key; that´s coming from <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>/?key=</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith> in the bucket.  if cloudfront will hit api gateway directy what key will pass?

Comment: The original request path will be received at API Gateway so you'll need to handle that a little differently.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. we will get there :) so.. the lambda function shouldn´t redirect to cloudfront anymore? what should return after transforming and saving the image in the right path?

Comment: hey @Michael - sqlbot  I updated the question and added details about what´s going on. in short. lambda is not getting invoked. can you take a look please? thank you!!

Comment: hello @Michael - sqlbot can you look ay my updated question with details when you have time? thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @handsome you added the origin configuration but did you change the Cache Behavior to actually use it?

Comment: not sure honestly. I created an origin group (1. s2 2. api gateway) then in behavior i chose the newly created origin group. should I set maximum TTL 0 there? I´m confused about that part. thanks!!

Comment: can you take a look please? sorry for bugging. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same implementation and got stuck also with the same problem. But, here's my solution:

1. On your lambda function on the success response add in the `headers` set `cache-control` to `must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate` would look something like this. `{ "headers": { "cache-control": "must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate" } }`. This will force to revalidate the files that you've just make.
2. (**Optional**) Go to your **CloudFront Distribution** -> **Error Page** -> **Create Custom Error Response** then set the TTL to 0 for the HTTP Error Code 400 this will terminate the cached error from CloudFront.

*Note*: The trade-off here is the waiting time when creating new dimension would become noticeable.